# Open Graph Action and Object Resubmission

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

As I submit an application for "read" action on Open Graph I received the following response.

> Status: Changes needed
>   Unfortunately, your article.read built-in submission does not meet the read requirements specified at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read. You must give users the ability to turn sharing off/on globally as well as remove an article that was shared within the app. In addition, read actions should only be generated when there is a strong indication that the user is actually reading the article. Please note that we cannot accept resubmission as this time due to technical limitations, so you will need to create a new submission. We plan to have this resolved within the next couple of weeks. We suggest making the required changes and checking back. We appreciate your patience. Note: If you are creating an aggregation based on the object, you need to add 6-7 unique sample objects, and then create a corresponding sample action acting on each of these unique objects. (You can not just create 6-7 sample actions pointing to the same sample object). Submission Checklist: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/checklist
>   Please make changes below and resubmit for review.

Unfortunately, this "guide" is not helping with anything. Firstly, I have no idea where to do this:

> You must give users the ability to turn sharing off/on globally as well as remove an article that was shared within the app.

Second of all, I don't even know how to "resubmit"!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should implement a toggle on/off list whoch save data in broswer's cookies

Comment: Maybe people who don’t understand _how_ to create a comfortable user experience even if _explicitly_ told what to do … shouldn’t be building apps in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same thing.  You have to click on the name of your action that you submitted.  Once you do that, Facebook provides detailed instructions why they didn't approve the action and what you need to do before you resubmit.  Once you review the message, you can make the necessary changes and save the action again.  Then you'll have the option to resubmit.  In my case Facebook said that I need to provide more detailed instructions what the user needs to do to get an action published.  They provided this example: "User must create an account, enable Timeline sharing in the settings, view a product within the app and then click the “want” button underneath the product image to trigger a story".  I did that and resubmitted.  Hopefully it works this time around.  Good luck.

Comment: wow @Andy Idema very informative answer indeed.. **where** is this _option to resubmit_?

Answer (score 0):

To resubmit, just delete the rejected action and create a new one. You can use the same action name as before. You then go through the submission process again as you did the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook have recently updated their guide to implementing their built-in action types. For the `Read` action type, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read. You will see a sample application that meets the following criteria required for the use of this action type:

1. Turn sharing on/off globally on each page an article appears.
2. Remove articles they shared within your app on each page an article appears.
3. Only generate read actions when you're sure someone is interested in reading the article.

Comment: Can you link to the sample app that meets the listed criteria, I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @gotomanners There is no physical app to use as an example on that page, just the mocked-up screenshots. The implementation on one of my client's sites has been accepted for use with the 'read' action when viewing news articles. See [Direct2Mum](http://www.direct2mum.co.uk).

Answer (score 0):

Built-In actions can't be resubmitted. It is a FB Bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/364663400220101?browse=search_4f44876aabaef7501649601

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/766212650082136/) answer on FB *tools and support* I got this:

> You can start a new submission at the bottom of the "Items in Review" page:
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/apps/337449599791917/review-status/items-in-review/

That link didn't work for me.. so I just went to the app dashboard and clicked on *status and review*

[image]

clicking on the **start a new submission** button loaded a dialog that prompted me to select which items to "re-review".. so I only selected the problematic one:

[image]

after that it loads a form for you to resubmit, so here you gotta re-upload the iOS simulator build etc..

[image]

and that's it!